# How to use gcm(Google Cloud Messaging) in Kivy?

Tags: android, python, kivy

Hello I'm trying to develop an app with Kivy.

I figured that gcm needs to download its gcm lib to project file.

1. Can kivy use gcm with pyjnius plyer?
2. How can I run kivy app in the background of android so I can get notification even the app is down.